# Creating data lake causes error code 403 or 409. checking for existence of existing File System and then never finds it in azure terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm working on some terraform code and I have it set up that I call a module that is a storage account and data lake module. I call that to my main repo to work on it. The issue is I keep getting various error codes from the different runs I've made

Error: checking for existence of existing File System "examplenameofdl" (Account "sadl123"): datalakestore.Client#GetProperties: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: error response cannot be parsed: {"" '\x00' '\x00'} error: EOF

and
checking for existence of existing File System "examplenameofdl" (Account "sadl123"): datalakestore.Client#GetProperties: Failure sending request: StatusCode=409 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=

Here is the code I'm using for the storage account/ data lake

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "storage_account" {
  name                              = var.name
  location                          = var.location
  resource_group_name               = var.rg_name
  tags                              = var.tags
  account_tier                      = var.account_tier
  account_replication_type          = var.account_replication_type
  account_kind                      = var.account_kind
  access_tier                       = var.access_tier
  is_hns_enabled                    = var.hnsenabled
  network_rules {
    default_action             = var.default_network_action
    ip_rules                   = var.ip_rules
    virtual_network_subnet_ids = var.virtual_network_subnet_ids
    bypass                     = var.bypass_network_rules
  }
}

resource "azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem" "example" {
  count              = var.dlenabled ? 1 : 0 //this is to check if the data lake is needed
  name               = "examplenameofdl"
  storage_account_id = azurerm_storage_account.storage_account.id
  properties = {
    hello = "aGVsbG8="
  }

}
```

This is then called into a separate repo that has the variables where the resource group is created and then passed to it from a separate module. Whenever it's run it causes this error

```
│ Error: checking for existence of existing File System "examplenameofdl" (Account "sadl123"): datalakestore.Client#GetProperties: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: error response cannot be parsed: {"" '\x00' '\x00'} error: EOF
│ 
│   with module.storage_account1["sa-01"].azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem.example[0],
│   on .terraform/modules/storage_account1/main.tf line 76, in resource "azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem" "example":
│   76: resource "azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem" "example" {
```

It never creates the file system so why is it checking for the existence of it? I've tried assigning permissions to the resource group to have Storage Blob Data Owner

```
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "role_assignment" {
  scope                = azurerm_resource_group.spoke_rgs["sadl-rg-01"].id
  role_definition_name = "Storage Blob Data Owner"
  principal_id         = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id
}
```

I've also tried to assign the storage account the same permissions, but nothing gets rid of this error. I'm completely lost on how to proceed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**

*Initially I tried same process and got a same error.*

**Console:**

[image]

According to this [Document](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem), if you need to create data lake file system it requires roles like **`Storage blob contributor, storage blob data owner, storage account contributor, storage blob data reader.`**

You can assign through portal and also terraform:

```
data "azurerm_subscription" "primary" {
}

data "azurerm_client_config" "example" {
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "example" {
  scope                = data.azurerm_subscription.primary.id
  role_definition_name = "storage blob data owner"
  principal_id         = data.azurerm_client_config.example.object_id
}
```

**Portal:**

[image]

**`terraform.tf`**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "example-vnet"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "example-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
  service_endpoints    = ["Microsoft.Storage"]
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "venky326"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
   account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
  account_kind             = "StorageV2"
  is_hns_enabled           = "true"
  
  tags = {
    environment = "staging"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account_network_rules" "example" {
  storage_account_id = azurerm_storage_account.example.id

  default_action             = "Allow"
  ip_rules                   = ["127.0.0.1"]
  virtual_network_subnet_ids = [azurerm_subnet.example.id]
  bypass                     = ["Metrics"]
}

resource "azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem" "example" {
  name               = "datelake132"
  storage_account_id = azurerm_storage_account.example.id

  properties = {
    hello = "aGVsbG8="
  }
}
```

After assigning role to storage account, the code executed successfully.

**Console:**

[image]

**Portal:**
[image]

> checking for existence of existing File System "examplenameofdl" (Account "sadl123"): datalakestore.Client#GetProperties: Failure sending request: StatusCode=409 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=

The above 409 error indicates in a small period of time,if the code in your application deletes and then immediately recreates a blob container with the same name.

**Reference:**
[Troubleshoot client application errors in Azure Storage accounts | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/troubleshoot-storage-client-application-errors?tabs=dotnet#the-client-is-receiving-http-403-forbidden-messages)